# Creating a Virtual machine using Azure command line tool for linux

Tags: linux, command-line, azure, passwords, virtual-machine

Trying to use Azure command line tool for linux,

Below is the screen output when i am trying to create a vm.

path.existsSync is now called `fs.existsSync`.
info:    Executing command vm create
+ Looking up image
+ Looking up cloud service
+ Creating cloud service
+ Retrieving storage accounts
tty.setRawMode: Use `process.stdin.setRawMode()` instead.
Enter VM 'cliusername' password:

At this stage,I entered the password and hit enter but nothing more happens.Also what is the  message "tty.setRawMode: Use `process.stdin.setRawMode()` instead." that is shown on the screen.Plz help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I had discussion with respective team, we figure it out that this problem is related to node.js v0.8 compatibility issue.

It seems that you are running latest node version and the azure tool you installed using following command are not compatible with latest node v0.8:

```
npm install azure --global
```

The fix is there in the DEV branch https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/ NOT in MASTER. The package served from the npm repository is not updated with this.

For the time being you can create package from dev branch, for this:

1. Download the zip file from https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/dev
2. Unzip and from the command prompt switch to extracted directory
3. Create the package by running the command (Note: This will generate the file azure-0.6.1.tgz):

   **npm pack**
4. Install this package by running the command:

   **npm install azure-0.6.1.tgz --global**

This should solve your problem.