# Azure-cli installation failed

Tags: ubuntu, azure, npm

I've troubles with installation of azure command line tools:

> npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: azure-cli 
>   npm ERR! No valid targets found. 
>   npm ERR! Perhaps not compatible with your version of node? 
>   npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-51-generic-pae 
>   npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "azure-cli" "-g" 
>   npm ERR! cwd /home/leonid/Repositories/azure-sdk-for-node 
>   npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12 
>   npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4 
>   npm ERR! message No compatible version found: azure-cli 
>   npm ERR! message No valid targets found. 
>   npm ERR! message Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?

I've tried solution from: [[Creating a Virtual machine using Azure command line tool for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519071)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519071), but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you share the version of Node you're using? If it really is 0.6.12, that's very old, as there have been years of newer versions. Try using a current version of Node from your package manager or Nodejs.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added PPA: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/chris_lea_nodejs:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js 
>   sudo apt-get update 
>   sudo apt-get remove nodejs 
>   sudo apt-get install nodejs

After that I got an error:

> npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

To solve it, I changed my config:

> npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org" 
>   npm config set strict-ssl false

After that it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, uninstall the outdated version :

`sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm`

Then enable nodesource's repo and install:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

I solve this error in my debian machine.